# Как разбить строку на английские и русские токены (включая одинаковые символы)

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Необходимо разбить строку на токены, включая разделители, для того что бы можно было собрать из токенов снова строку.

Строка содержит английские и русские слова, причём и русские и английские слова могут иметь одинаковые символы, например хештег, нижнее подчеркивание и цифры, пример:
**«первое_слово! firtst_word.. #слово2, #word2, я, z, _»**. (Это всего-лишь пример, текст может быть абсолютно любым и начинаться и заканчиваться с любого знака)
Нужно получить токены:

0: «первое_слово»

1: «! »

2: «firtst_word»

3: «.. »

4: «#слово2»

5: «, »

6: «#word2»

7: «, »

8: «я»

9: «, »

10: «z»

11: «, »

13: «_»

При написании регулярного выражения исхожу из принципа: думаю не по какому выражению разбить строку, а, наоборот, что включить в токены.

**Пробовал регулярное выражение:
[а-яА-ЯёЁ0-9_#]+|[a-zA-Z0-9_#]+|[ .,!]+**

И все бы хорошо, но!
Если любой из символов, который повторяется и в русской части и в английской находится в середине слова - то все хорошо. **А если этот символ стоит в начале слова, то регулярное выражение не даёт токены под номерами 4 и 6, а разбивает один из токенов дополнительно ещё на два # и word2 (а должно быть слитно!)**
Смешивать английский и русский диалект тоже нельзя, для них специально написано две разных регулярки (так, например, специальный символ @ в английском слове является частью слова, а в русском слове - это токен разделитель). В регулярке не отразил этот момент, что бы не перегружать суть.

Comment: Стоит указать, какой диалект регулярок используется. И где он используется, в редакторе или в программе, если в программе — какой язык программирования (возможно, там есть более удобные методы деления текста на токены).

Comment: Хорошо, что добавили про смешивание алфавитов — как видно из моего ответа, это может быть существенным для решения.

Answer (score 1):

Так получается, потому что регулярка пытается применить сначала первую из альтернатив, и если находит часть нужных символов (хештег), она уже не возвращается, если дальше идут неподходящие (латиница вместо кириллицы), а начинает новую попытку и в ней применяет первую подошедшую альтернативу (уже с латиницей).

Есть, например, такие варианты решения.

1. Объедините варианты с кириллицей и латиницей (если невозможны слова со смесью алфавитов или если они тоже валидны). Пример регулярки и использования на JavaScript: `/[а-яё\w#]+|[ .,!]+/gi` (использован флаг игнорирования регистра и класс `\w`, который включает в себя основную латиницу, цифры и подчёркивание):

```js
console.log(
  'первое_слово! firtst_word.. #слово2, #word2, я, z, _'
  .match(/[а-яё\w#]+|[ .,!]+/gi)
  .join('\n')
);
```

2. Если смешивать алфавиты нельзя и ваш диалект регулярок поддерживает заглядывание вперёд и назад, добавьте в альтернативы проверки, требующие, чтобы словесный токен окружали только допустимые несловесные разедилители или начало / конец строки. Пример регулярки и использования на JavaScript: `(/(?<=[ .,!]|^)[а-яё0-9_#]+(?=[ .,!])|(?<=[ .,!])[\w#]+(?=[ .,!]|$)|[ .,!]+/gi` (те же особенности, что и в предыдущем варианте плюс добавлены проверки с заглядыванием вперёд и назад вокруг каждой словесной альтернативы).

```js
console.log(
  'первое_слово! firtst_word.. #слово2, #word2, я, z, _'
  .match(/(?<=[ .,!]|^)[а-яё0-9_#]+(?=[ .,!])|(?<=[ .,!])[\w#]+(?=[ .,!]|$)|[ .,!]+/gi)
  .join('\n')
);
```

Последнюю регулярку можно заменить на `/(?<=[ .,!]|^)(?:[а-яё0-9_#]+|[\w#]+)(?=[ .,!])|[ .,!]+/gi`, если она покажется более читабельной:

```js
console.log(
  'первое_слово! firtst_word.. #слово2, #word2, я, z, _'
  .match(/(?<=[ .,!]|^)(?:[а-яё0-9_#]+|[\w#]+)(?=[ .,!])|[ .,!]+/gi)
  .join('\n')
);
```